# Get reports from SSRS with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need help setting up SSRS and Laravel to work with our windows server.

I want to **get reports** from SSRS with Laravel web application by using URL.

*Example URL:*

> http://192.168.0.22:100/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2freportst%2fReportExample**&name=John&surname=Doe**&rs:Command=Render

SSRS needs to send reports to web server, web server(Laravel app) will return it to client browser. In that way I'm not exposing URL and parameters between SSRS and web server.

I want to retrieves report with php file_get_contents() method. But I can't get access to SSRS report because of Windows authentication that SSRS i asking for everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a solution of this type to use with laravel and I found a library that worked perfectly for me, see on github if it suits you too.

There are some basic examples in the repository, follow the link

https://github.com/ChartBlocks/php-ssrs